# Concrete5 not allowing pushing default composer control to child pages

Tags: php, concrete5

I've edited my page defaults in concrete5 and have a frustrating problem - when I add a composer control, I cannot push the change to existing pages. When adding e.g. a page title it works:

[image]

but when adding a composer control there's no option to push it to child pages.

[image]

This basically means that I have to recreate all my pages if I want to take advantage of the new default component.

Is there any kind of a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a C5 bug that is still waiting to be fixed. If memory serves a fix was added to the core but I think it turned out to not be totally solving the problem and was pulled back.

You might want to update to the latest version and see if it fixes the problem but really no guarantee.

The only other alternative is to make sure you really plan your page types well before using them. I know it sucks a bit.